# A menu link that points to specfic place on a page (I can't use anchors)

Tags: files, navigation

I have some embedded pdfs on my site using PDF Reader module, which is working great.  But my boss wants a link to a specific place in one of those pdfs.  Thus I need some way to add a link to the main menu, that will take the user to the page with the embedded pdf, and then automatically scroll down to the proper spot in the multi-page pdf.

I've looked at both the jquery.scrollTo module and the jquery.scrollTo script, but I can't see how to use these without using #anchors, which I cannot put into the middle of my embedded pdfs.

Is jquery.scrollTo the right way to go? Something else?

Thanks in advance,
Peace Corps Volunteer, In Way Over His Head

Comment: This is very much what anchors are for, any particular reason you can't use them?

Comment: I have nowhere to put them.  I am trying to link to the middle of a long pdf document that is being rendered using PDF Reader module/pdf.js.  What I am looking for is someway to have a link in the main menu, that once clicked will have take the user to the page with the pdf and then scroll down a set number of pixels or to one of the unique DIVs being generated by PDF Reader Module/pdf.js.  I can't see a way to insert an anchor into the html being generated by pdf.js.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but I found this forum post and thought it might help you:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/13098

Answer (score 0):

Its simple! You just create a link and go to page content edit option through Drupal admin. In the bottom of edit content page you will get a URL path settings, there is url alias field on there. You just put path in your field.[image]